# When i get html file or call any service from the server, The responce contains red dot in chrome network tab which cause HTML/JSON break

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm using `AngularJs` as front end and `Spring` `Java` as backend. For calling the service I have used `$resource` service of `Angular`. I also included `html` files in my project using `ng-include` and called services using $resource.

This basically gives rise to the random issues in the application like seeing parts of code lines on the UI of the application or complete broken UI. Also many a times we get the broken `JSON` responses of Services called using $resource and serviced by Spring.

HTML break response:

[image: 1]

HTML break response:

[image: 2]

Comment: There are no starting `div` tags in the response that you are getting from server. So the UI doesnt know how to render that

Comment: It seems that we are getting incomplete/corrupted response from server.